# Qt Creator - No CMake executable was found in this path

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

When opening a CMakeList.txt file with QtCreator, it asks me to provide the path to the CMake executable. I navigate to `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe` where `cmake.exe` is, however QtCreator says:

> No CMake executable was found in the path.

I tried looking around Qt code to see what it uses to validate the `cmake.exe`, however there were too many indirections, so I couldn't quite figure it out. What seems to be the problem? Is it the name of the exe?

Comment: Is CMake a x64 program? Mine is installed in `Program Files (x86)`. Also, is cmake's bin folder in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: It's on Windows 7 32-bit, so I only have one Program Files folder. I am using CMake 3.3.1. Adding the bin directory to PATH didn't help tho.

Comment: Did you restart creator after making the environment change?

Comment: you may also want to check this out if you haven't seen it: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html

Comment: Yes, I'm doing exactly that, however Qt Creator doesn't seem to recognize the cmake.exe. I added the bin directory to PATH and restarted QtCreator to no avail.

Comment: Does it work to run cmake from the cmd? If not, then your PATH is broken. If yes, your Qt Creator is somehow broken.